# Progress bar in iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, progress-bar

I have main jsp page which has two iframe where as
first iframe loads menu **(i.e. leftFrame)** & other loads dynamic pages according to menu.**(i.e. mainFrame)**
My question is while loading any page in second iframe i have to show spinner ***(progress bar)***.
How can i code it in jquery.

Here is the code

```
<body>
  <table>
<tr>
    <td style="height:100%"><iframe name="leftFrame" id="leftFrame" src="leftnavigation.jsp" height="600" width="200" frameborder="0"></iframe></td>

    <td style="height:100%"><iframe name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" src="news.jsp"  height="600" width="1000" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"> </iframe></td>

</tr>   

</table>
</body>
```

[image] Spinner.gif

What would be the script.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to add a progress indicator for your IFrame you can achieve it by putting a transparant CSS overlay on top of the Iframe and rendering the loading indicator on top of the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by `.ready` function of jquery. All you have to do is place a transparent  division on top of your iFrame having yout loading image in center. And fadeout the division when the iFrame is ready.

I have made a demo for this. See [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UHuKG/4/).

Not perfect designing, but you will get the idea.